# prevent closing a tab and show a model window instead of default dialogue using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want prevent user to close a tab and need to enter password to close the tab. is it possible to show custom message. I tried onbeforeunload but shows default dialogue

Comment: Forcing a user to enter a password in order to close a tab would be bad security on the browser's part, as there are a lot of ways that could be exploited. I don't know for 100% so I'm not posting as an answer, but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

Comment: It sounds like you're building a virus, fortunately it's not possible.

Comment: ohh Nooo!!!. It is to put test. I need to prevent student from closing tabs.. @Teemu

Comment: I can understand such a feature would sometimes be useful, but as @fin444 stated, "_there are a lot of ways that could be exploited_", that's why it's not implemented in any browser.

Comment: ok i understood. Thanks